# matplotlib 3.2.1: inconsistent size of stix mathfont with Times New Roman normal font for certain font sizes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've recently been having an issue with the stix mathtext fontset when formatting plots made using matplotlib (3.2.1).

I'm running:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.8

I have noticed a strange result when running the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

# mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)

mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Times New Roman'
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'stix'
mpl.rcParams['font.size'] = 12 # <---- THIS LINE

x = np.arange(10)
y = 2*x

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_xlabel('X $X$')
ax.set_ylabel('Y $Y$')

plt.show()
```

I get math text which is noticeably smaller than normal text for certain font sizes.  For example the above code with font size 12 generates this plot with inconsistent font size:
[image: fontsize 12]

but setting the font size to 14 gives consistent math and normal font size:

```
mpl.rcParams['font.size'] = 14
```

[image: font 14]

Any suggestions appreciated! Please let me know if I can provide more info.

Thanks